# How to get all HttpHeaders as a ResponseBody in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, httprequest

I need to get the all HttpHeaders and then need to back all of these as a key-value pair as a `ResponseBody`. How can I achieve this?

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class Employee {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> hello(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is with your return type. Have you tried `ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<String>>` because in the end that is what it basically is. If you are certain it only contains single values you can also use `headers.toSingleValueMap`.

Comment: Hi, I've tried with ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<String>>. But at then headers.toSingleValueMap() doesn't work. Because toSinglevalueMap() returns <Map<String,String>>. Any idea? @M. Deinum

Comment: YOu don't need `toSingleValueMap` then as `HttpHeaders` is a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: You are right @M.Deinum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> hello(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(headers.toSingleValueMap());
}
```

Though `HttpHeaders` is an implementation of `Map`, it is not well serialized into JSON. The method [`HttpHeaders#toSingleValueMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpHeaders.html#toSingleValueMap()) returns `Map<String, String>`.

```bash
curl http://localhost:8080/employee --header 'foo: bar'
```

> ```json
> {
>   "foo": "bar",
> }
> ```

Comment: Need one clarification. HttpHeaders will always be <key,value> (<String,String>)? There is no option to have <String,Object> like this? If it happens, how will I Map then? @Nikolas

Comment: Each header is always a key-value structure where both key and value are text, no matter how complex thing you put inside, that's why `toSingleValueMap` always returns `Map<String, String>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class Employee {
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> hello(HttpHeaders headers) {
        Map<String, String> headersMap = headers.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().get(0)));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(headersMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide another way to obtain the header information of the request using httpServletRequest

```java
package com.mmd.look.web.api.common;

import com.mmd.look.common.response.Result;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Enumeration;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class Employee {
    @GetMapping
    public Result<Void> hello(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = headerNames.nextElement();
            String header = httpServletRequest.getHeader(name);
            System.out.println(name + ":" + header);
        }
        return Result.ok("");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to writing this functionality in a Spring Cloud Gateway application which doesn't use Serverlet, it runs on Netty runtime. So, this would not be a use case for me. But, this is applicable for any Spring Boot application.